# c++ lambda expression confusion

Tags: c++11, lambda

I feel confused about lambda in c++.Is it related to the compiler?
The following code run correct in ubuntu g++ 4.6.3 and g++ 5.2. But when I run it in centos 4.8.5,the result is error.

```
// 
class ScopeGuard
{
 public:
    explicit ScopeGuard(std::function<void ()> onExitScope)
      :onExitScope_(onExitScope)
 {

 }

   ~ScopeGuard()
  {
     onExitScope_();
  }
private:
  std::function<void ()> onExitScope_;
};
```

And there is a function to uncompress the data.

```
//
...
int dstLen = 10 * 1024 * 1024;
char *dstBuf = new char[dstLen];
// When I comment this line the err return Z_OK, otherwise return Z_BUFF_ERROR.
ScopeGuard guard([&](){if (dstBuf) delete[] dstBuf; dstBuf=NULL;});

// zlib function. 
int err = uncompress((Bytef *)dstBuf, (uLongf*)&dstLen, (Bytef*)src, fileLen);

if (err != Z_OK)
{
    cout<<"uncompress error..."<<err<<endl;
    return false;
}`
```

Comment: The return value of function uncompress is Z_BUFF_ERR only when I run the code in centos g++ 4.8.5. when I annotate the ScopeGuard, It return Z_OK.

Comment: Also, CentOS is not a compiler; what's the actual compiler and its version?

Comment: When I run in centos with gcc version 4.8.5, the result is error.

Comment: When you say "annotate", do you mean "comment"?

Comment: Perhaps the call to `new char[dstLen]` fails in CentOS because you're requesting too much memory. Are you using the throwing version of `new`?

Comment: Yes,thanks,actually no matter what code it is in lambda, the result is error,unless comment 'ScopeGuard.....'.I try upgrading gcc's version in centos.

Answer (score 1):

This is most likely because of this: `(uLongf*)&dstLen`.

`dstLen` is an `int`, which is 32 bits and all current typical systems. `uLongf`, however, is an alias for `unsigned long`, which is 32 bits on Windows and 32-bit *nix systems, but 64 bits on 64-bit *nix systems.

It is not safe, and likely to do the wrong thing, to cast an `int*` to an `uLongf*`.

The solution is to make `dstLen` an `uLongf` and remove the cast.

Comment: Yes, thanks a lot! I solved the problem with this method.

Comment: The ubuntu is 32-bit,but centos is 64-bit